# Avoid network request when using images already in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to avoid network requests when adding images to the DOM tree that already exist somewhere in the current DOM? By adding I mean cloning an existing node, creating a new node and appending an image that is already in the DOM etc.

EDIT: I am building an image slider with category filtering. At first, all the images are shown. When I change the category, I am getting requests with a 200 response for each image that changed.

Is that something that will be handled automatically by the server? I am working on the front-end part currently, so I am not sure what will happen when the site is served from a proper web server.

Comment: Can't you add proper caching headers to the http response? The browser will automatically solve this for you this way.

Comment: If the image is already in the DOM it will be in browser's cache. So even if you see a request for it, it'll probably have a 304 response code, meaning that there's no real request to the server.

Comment: I added some clarifications to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I had the 'Disable cache' button checked in dev tools. Sorry!